# Ionic and purchases in Google Play?

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

A situation that can not be solved for more than 4 days ... 
Realizing opportunity app purchases on Google Play. 
The application is written in Ionic, Angular first version. For purchases using a library Disler by Alex [cordova-plugin-inapppurchase](https://github.com/AlexDisler/cordova-plugin-inapppurchase)

Chronology of what I did: 
1) Set **cordova plugin add cc.fovea.cordova.purchase --variable BILLING_KEY = " My key "** 
2) add to the manifest.json:

```
{" play_store_key ":" MyRSA key "}
```

3) AndroidManifest added permission for billing:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BILLING" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
```

4) In the Template page I have button with loading poducts and field with foreach of product list.

5) The controller file:

```
$scope.loadProducts = function () {
      $ionicLoading.show({ template: spinner + 'Loading Products...' });

      alert('If Isset inAppPurchase: ' + inAppPurchase);

      inAppPurchase
      .getProducts(productIds)
      .then(function (products) {
        $ionicLoading.hide();
        alert('If Isset products: ' + products);
        $scope.products = products;
      })
      .catch(function (err) {
        $ionicLoading.hide();
        alert('Error: ' + err);
        alert(err);
      });
    };
```

6) Create a build: cordova build --release android, sign, archive and install to a real phone. 
7) On Google Play have the same version of the android - beta, status Published. 2 Products in Active status.

Q: What have I forgotten? I did not finish? By clicking on the button to receive all of the products, the result - an empty array on success of promise. I would appreciate any comments!

Answer (score 0):

i recntly had the same problem.  What I did is to include the product id i defined into the array variable in the controller as follows:

```
var productIds = ["productid1","productid2" ]; // <- Add your product Ids here
```